# How to prevent SPAM email from Yahoo Mail?

Tags: email, blocking, spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

I am receiving same SPAM from Yahoo Mail. Accounts look to be different only having 8 random characters everytime like this:

**hfirnybp**@yahoo.com

**ncbfkuop**@yahoo.com

**opaswtui**@yahoo.com

How to block these emails? I don't want to completely block all email from Yahoo.

Comment: FYI, those e-mail addresses are likely not real. It's not difficult for spammers to send e-mail with fake "from" addresses; it sounds like the people targeting you are just generating eight characters at random and appending "@yahoo.com."

Comment: IME, Gmail has the best spam filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple solution:**
Use a decent spam filter.

**Reason:**
The addresses that appear to come from Yahoo are most probably not really originating from there. They are randomly generated, as you observed, and their real origin is a different mail server.

One can always fake the sender's e-mail address, but any reasonably good spam filter will recognize this and categorize the mail as spam. Not to mention that the mail's content will also be identifiable as such too.

As you don't say which e-mail provider you have or which client you use, I can only guess. But [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) has a good spam filter that will also learn based on what you categorize as spam and what you say not. That way any "real" Yahoo mails will never be marked as spam, whereas the fake ones are caught.

Comment: I use Hotmail free email.

Comment: Do you use the spam filter? (I guess it's called SmartScreen or something)

Comment: for future security never share your email id any where in the internet.